# required field - validation doesn't display in bootstrap modal popup MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add product in my website. When I click create a product I must enter some value. When trying to save without any data, you want to check that validation work. It work, but when I click submit the form is not in modal popup (image2) - it display like other site

I want to like this (image1) - display in modal popup

- [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y8Dy.png)
- [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc3l2.png)

Validation highlighted in red is Polish but it means that the fields are required.

I use formData because I must send a file.

**modalform.js**

```
var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: formdata,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                } else {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

I'm using AJAX posting to submit the data from my form. When using $(this).serialize() the ajax success is being called but the file is not returning as the content type is different. How can I change this??

**Model**

```
public partial class Produkty
    {
        public int PRO_Id { get; set; }
        public string PRO_Nazwa { get; set; }
        public string PRO_Jednostka { get; set; }
        public float PRO_Vat { get; set; }
        public string PRO_Rodzaj { get; set; }
        public string PRO_Opis { get; set; }
        public string PRO_Waluta { get; set; }
        public float PRO_CenaN { get; set; }
        public float PRO_CenaB { get; set; }
        public string PRO_ZdjecieN { get; set; }
        public byte[] PRO_ZdjecieF { get; set; }
    }
```

**Create View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
//@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PRO_Nazwa, "Nazwa", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PRO_Nazwa, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRO_Nazwa, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PRO_Jednostka, "Jednostka", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PRO_Jednostka, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "szt." } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRO_Jednostka, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PRO_Vat, "Vat", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PRO_Vat, new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "23 %", Value = "23"},
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "8 %", Value = "8" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "5 %", Value = "5" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "4 %", Value = "4" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "0 %", Value = "0" }

                    }, "wybierz...", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Value1" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRO_Vat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PRO_Rodzaj, "Rodzaj", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PRO_Rodzaj, new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "towar", Value = "towar" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "usługa", Value = "usługa" }

                    }, "wybierz...", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRO_Rodzaj, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PRO_Waluta, "Waluta", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PRO_Waluta, new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "PLN", Value = "PLN" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "EUR", Value = "EUR" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "USD", Value = "USD" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "GBP", Value = "GBP" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "CHF", Value = "CHF" }

                    }, "wybierz...", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRO_Waluta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PRO_CenaN, "Cena netto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PRO_CenaN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Value2" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRO_CenaN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PRO_CenaB, "Cena brutto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PRO_CenaB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "MultiplyValue1Value2" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRO_CenaB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PRO_Opis, "Opis", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PRO_Opis, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "brak" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRO_Opis, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PRO_ZdjecieF, "Plik", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="file" id="file" class ="btn btn-default btn-file" name="file" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRO_ZdjecieF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Anuluj</button>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" id="upload" type="submit" value="Zapisz" />
    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "PRO_ZdjecieF,PRO_Zdjecie")]Produkty pro, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {           


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //if (imageF != null)
                {
                    pro.PRO_ZdjecieF = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    pro.PRO_ZdjecieN = file.ContentType;
                    file.InputStream.Read(pro.PRO_ZdjecieF, 0, file.ContentLength);
                }

                db.Produkties.Add(pro);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { success = true });
            }

            return PartialView("Create", pro);
        }
```

Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Add the validations in the model class

```
public partial class Produkty
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]

        public int PRO_Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]

        public string PRO_Nazwa { get; set; }
        public string PRO_Jednostka { get; set; }
        public float PRO_Vat { get; set; }
        public string PRO_Rodzaj { get; set; }
        public string PRO_Opis { get; set; }
        public string PRO_Waluta { get; set; }
        public float PRO_CenaN { get; set; }
        public float PRO_CenaB { get; set; }
        public string PRO_ZdjecieN { get; set; }
        public byte[] PRO_ZdjecieF { get; set; }
    }
```

Add this code in your view page

```
   $('#form1').removeData('validator');
   $('#form1').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
   $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#form1');
```

Comment: work :) thanks.

How can I validate (in this same modal popup) if the entry already exists in the database?

Comment: what kind of validation do you want to do in popup?

Comment: this same like in image1 if PRO_Nazwa field exists in dataase

Comment: i cant see the image , its blocked